# Exclude strings from search PhpStorm

Tags: php, replace, phpstorm, project

This question might have an answer somewhere out there in the internet but I can't seem to find it. Of course if you have a link to give me I will gladly accept it as an answer if it is what I am looking for.

***Here goes:***
***How can I exclude some strings from my global search ?***

Basically I use the <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd> to find all occurrences of a `nameOfTheFile.php` string to find all the patterns that call this file. A not so very smart developer created multiple `nameOfTheFile.php` everywhere and so the path to include them always changes, I need something fix so I need to change every single call. There is a lot of calls => 1533 occurrences according to PhpStorm so doing them one by one is NOT an option.

So my plan is to write all the patterns down (there shouldn't be more than 50 so it is doable) and replace all of them later. To do that I could use a **filter to exclude the patterns that I have already found**.

At the moment the pattern list would be something like:

```
include_once("folderY/nameOfTheFile.php");
include_once(PATH . "folderY/nameOfTheFile.php");
include_once (PATH . "folderY/nameOfTheFile.php");
include_once ("../../../folderX/nameOfTheFile.php");
include_once ("../../folderX/nameOfTheFile.php");
include_once ("../folderX/nameOfTheFile.php");
require_once($settings['siteFilepath'] . "folderY/nameOfTheFile.php");
```

How can I exclude those strings from the search? I thought of using a Regex but as I am not an expert (Junior Dev here :/) I can't really come up with it. Also I would think that maybe there is something built in PhpStorm that could work better.

Have I missed something ? Is there a Regex to help me ? Bonus point: if there is a Regex please explain how it works (remember I am far from being an expert).

Comment: It would be possibly more useful for you to spend some time learning Regex and its operators and syntax so that you *can* use a Regex solution here and this will help you in becoming a *Senior* Developer that much quicker `;-)`

Comment: *"Show a man a Regex, and he will be happy for a day. Teach a man to Regex and he will be smiling all next year"*

Comment: @Martin while I do agree with you I would like to know if there is another solution first. I have had my share of experience with Regex and for something like that I don't think I have a good enough level nor can I obtain it quickly enough.

Comment: I unfortunately not fully following your design but you can toggle filters in Find in Path: https://i.gyazo.com/27036c922b0d8b15ffb2164fcdbb2ca8.png

Comment: @Ástþór These filters are not specific from what I understand. I can't filter out a call like I want to.

Answer (score 2):

in PhpStorm go to replace all cntr+shift+R
select 'Regex' option and enter

```
include_once.*nameOfTheFile\.php"\);
```

this will select offending entries for replacement

Comment: Thank you Georges, would it be possible for you to explain exactly how the Regex works ?

Comment: this specific query means find everything that starts with - 'include_once' followed by anything and ending with - nameOfTheFile.php");  \.- had to escaped as well as \) cause those are regex reserved commands

Comment: That is what I thought, I could also use it for the require_once. It helps thanks! Since it is not the actual answer I was looking for I won't validate it. Still I upvoted :)

Comment: Maybe if you could come up with a Regex that search for nameOfTheFile.php and ignores the include_once and require_once so I can check if there are some other calls. I know I am asking for a lot but that would solve my problem.

Comment: why not use native PhpStorm search for that? just search for nameOfTheFile.php normally it will show all entries

Comment: But that is the point I want to filter out some of the entries because there is a lot of them.

Comment: filter out by what criteria?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202008/discussion-between-dustman0-and-george-dryser).

Comment: @Dustman0 If you use `Find in Path` and then list all found results in a `Find Results` toolwindow (by using that button on the bottom in Find in Path popup), you will then be able to "remove" (delete) unwanted entry from the list (check content menu for that).

Comment: @Dustman0 Another option requires editing your source code by placing some marker on such "already-known-ignore-now" lines -- e.g. by placing `// ignore` or alike comment and modify your Regex to exclude such matches (I hope @GeorgeDryser can help with such Regex)

Comment: @LazyOne I was able to solve my problem with some Regex but I am still curious about your solution. That said I can't seem to find that 'FindResult' window you're talking about ? Could you create an answer and put some screens in it to be a bit more precise ? I would gladly accept that answer if it works as I intended :)

Comment: @LazyOne that is exactly what I ended doing

Comment: @Dustman0 1) https://postimg.cc/wRYNM3b2 2) https://postimg.cc/2LdZZmsD 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.2/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html 4) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.2/find-tool-window.html#contex

Comment: @LazyOne this is somewhat close to the solution except it only excludes 1 result. What I was looking for is to exclude all similar results so I can focus on the other ones. Trying to be as clear as possible but my lack of English vocabulary is making it hard.